# Why doesn't the output get redirected into the file?

Tags: perl, bash, redirect, output

I have the following command line that outputs vmstat every second with a time stamp on each line via the perl script:

```
vmstat 15 | /home/Beer/addtimestamp.pl > File_1
```

the contents of the addtimestamp.pl:

```
!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) { print localtime() . ": $_"; }
```

So why doesn't the output get redirected to the "File_1" file?

It works perfectly when I don't, it prints out the output perfectly every second with no issues at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When outputting to the terminal, perl's output is line buffered, so you will see every line as it is output. When its output is a file, it will be block buffered so you will not see any output until a full block is ready to write (4k I think, but variable and system-defined).

You need to set stdout to use line buffering:

```
$|=1;
```

Search for [perl line buffered output] and you'll see plenty of results about this.

Comment: I got it to work by starting my script with the above, Thanks you so Much!, I just wish it was Line buffered by default when its outputted to a file.

Thanks Again!!

Comment: Pedantically, better written as: `local $|=1;`

Comment: @cdarke What do you mean by adding 'local' ?

Comment: `local` ensures that the effect is localised, and should be used when changing any of the Perl system globals.  You don't absolutly need it here, but if you cut n' paste the code into a subroutine it ensures that the effect is local to that code block.

Comment: @i-am-l Trust me, you really don't wish it was line buffered by default.  The case where doing that would result in extremely bad performance is much more common than the case where it's inconvenient.